# Working with empty Doctrine 2 Association Objects

Tags: php, oop, zend-framework, doctrine-orm

When creating an association using Doctrine 2 and the Zend Framework, if the associated object is empty e.g. for entity->associated_entity->item if associated_entity is empty, i.e. there is not an associated entity to the original entity, then I get an error Trying to get property of non-object.

I know this is because I am trying to get the item from an empty entity.

What is the standard way to avoid this error?

I am using the code below to get the data, but because the initial associated entity will be returned as '', then it can't then get the item from ''

```
public function __get($name) 
{
    if (isset($this->$name)){
        return $this->$name;
    } else {
        return '';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try:

```
$associatedEntity = $entity->associated_entity;

if ($associatedEntity) {
    $item = $associatedEntity->item;
}
```

*Edit:*

OK then. Try putting this in your template/view:

```
<?php
$department = $instruction->department;

if ($department) {
    echo $department->department;
}
?>
```

*Edit 2 (after a small discussion in the chat :D):*

I think that there is no way to tell to PHP to stop the chain. E.g.
`$object1->object2->attribute`
If you write it this way, no matter what you put in the __get(), PHP will assume that object2 is an object and will try to fetch the requested attribute.

The easiest solution would be something like that:

```
<?php foreach ($this->data as $instruction) : ?>
    <?php if ($dep = $instruction->department) echo $dep->department ?>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Comment: can you show some code? I think it would be quite simple to solve

Comment: the error `Trying to get property of non-object` is not Doctrine 2 related but OOP-related

Comment: `$qb = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();
  $qb->add('select', 'i')
  ->add('from', 'S2\Entity\Tblinspectiondata i')
  ->add('orderBy', 'i.instdate asc');
  return $qb;`
is the query builder than is returned to the Zend Paginator, which populates the view with $this->view->data

`<?php foreach ($this->data AS $instruction){?>
<?= $instruction->department->department; ?>` 
in the Zend View

Comment: also: this `department->department` part looks strange. Your Models include Institutions that have Departments and those Departments have their own Departments?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9396/discussion-between-quanano-and-aletzo)